# Maximum numbers of ".." in relative URL in tinymce

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce-rails

I was trying to enter 4 double-dots in relative URL in tinymce like this

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z1d535wEoRS4RbNdm6y7Z6wcEmBB12nE

but it get reset to 3 double-dots, like this.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AhmLvxhIY-Kj6xujPFDwXXWbOLHxd0qj

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting "convert_urls: false" in tinymce.yml file for configuration.
Make sure to restart server